# Как реверсировать функцию?

Tags: javascript

(Моя задача - найти определенный флаг и вписать его в поле на сайте)

В процессе выполнения задания я столкнулся с проблемой, что я не могу понять, что делает ф-ция:

Непонятная функция:

`var n=1;for(i=0;i<28;i+=1)t+=e[n=420*n%29];return"fJbRXS_pKoAZvoSKfdZubxMsBWuWo"!=t?alert("NOT EPIC"):(alert("O M G"),window.location=window.location+o),!1})()`

Весь код:

```
function kek(){var e=document.getElementById("s").value,o=e,t={A:"E",B:"l",C:"N",D:"U",E:"v",F:"x",G:"D",H:"H",I:"Y",J:"W",K:"S",L:"k",M:"d",N:"j",O:"g",P:"m",Q:"h",R:"I",S:"r",T:"F",U:"z",V:"L",W:"e",X:"t",Y:"A",Z:"q",a:"f",b:"C",c:"w",d:"P",e:"B",f:"V",g:"i",h:"y",i:"T",j:"O",k:"b",l:"_",m:"M",n:"a",o:"Z",p:"X",q:"R",r:"J",s:"n",t:"G",u:"Q",v:"c",w:"p",x:"s",y:"o",z:"K",_:"u"};e=e.replace(/[A-Za-z_]/g,c=>t[c]);if(29!=e.length)return alert("NOT EPIC"),!1;t=e[0];var n=1;for(i=0;i<28;i+=1)t+=e[n=420*n%29];return"fJbRXS_pKoAZvoSKfdZubxMsBWuWo"!=t?alert("NOT EPIC"):(alert("O M G"),window.location=window.location+o),!1})()
```

Мои догадки:

1. Я так понимаю, что нам нужно идти с конца функции.
2. Я решил уравнение n=420*n%29 записанное в цикле I<28 и получил [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
3. И дальше возникает вопрос, нужно ли мне как то теперь идти от обратного и собирать этот флаг по индексам словаря или я вообще не туда пришел?

Пожалуйста, помогите найти флаг, или хотя бы понять, что делает данная функция.

Comment: я не понял о каком флаге идет речь: функция берет значение из поля, заменяет в полученной строке буквы, потом перемешивает символы в строке и сверяет с заданным значением, если совпало - добавляет в текущий урл значение из инпута и переходит по получившемуся адресу

Comment: @Grundy, вероятно речь о CTF

Comment: @Mattern, что за CTF?

Comment: @Grundy, Флаг - условный пароль, который сы отсюда должно как-то узнать

Comment: @Grundy, профессиональные совернования для ИБшников, где задача - достать "флаг" исходя из каких-то данных. В данном случае автор, скорее всего, столкнулся с заданием категории "web", где порой надо разреверстить js или еще что.

Comment: значением инпута может быть следующая строка: `ayyy_lmaoo_MwYrzeFqKpJkzkExJK`. @Mattern, То есть узнать что нужно ввести в input?

Comment: @Grundy, вообще задача - найти данные определенноно формата. Так как автор не приводит задачу полностью (что вообще было бы, как минимум, неспортивно), то мы не можем сказать точно. Вообще, вполне может быть, что вы здесь правы

Comment: Зачем портить свой вопрос?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, чтобы никто его не нашел :):):)

Comment: ayyy_lmaoo_MwYrzeFqKpJkzkExJK подтверждаю - это код который нужно ввести в input чтобы получить OMG

Comment: Добро пожаловать на stackoverflow на русском! Пожалуйста, не стоит вандализировать вопросы.